# How to get a zulu timezone representation of the current date

Tags: javascript, timezone, iso8601

I would like to get the current date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ([rfc3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)), Zulu format:

```
2015-10-13T10:26:43Z
```

How can I do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```
var isoDate = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(isoDate);
```

Hope it helps,